# Find probability of $X\leq Y$

Tags: probability

I have two random variables, $f_ X(x) = \left\{  \begin{array}{ll} \frac{2}{x^3}, &  \mbox{if $x \geq 1$}, \\ 0, &  \mbox{otherwise}. \end{array} \right.$.$f_ Y(y)=\frac{1}{2},$ uniform on$[0,2]$.Now I am trying to find $ {\bf P}(X\leq Y)$.

Using the total probability theorem, $$P \left[ X < Y \right] = \int P \left[ X < y \right] f_Y \left( y
   \right) \mathrm{d} y = \int F_X \left( y \right) f_Y \left( y \right)
   \mathrm{d} y$$.
$$F _X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x} f _X(t)dt=-\frac{1}{x^2}$$

Therefore, I got$$P \left[ X < Y \right] = \int_{0}^{2} -\frac{1}{y^2}\frac{1}{2}dy=\frac{1}{2y}$$

I am stuck here. It is invalide for $y=0$ when calculating$\frac{1}{2y}$. But I can't find where I make the mistake in my derivation. Could someone kindly point it out?

Comment: Doesn't it worry you in the least that $F_X(x)$ which is the **probability** that $X$ is no larger than $x$, works out to be the _negative_ number $-\frac{1}{x^2}$? Whatever happened to the First Axiom of Probability which insists that probabilities are nonnegative numbers?

Comment: Sigh, I lost the common sense about basic concept. Thank you for pointing  it out.

Comment: @André Nicolas, intuitively, how to get this result without calculation?

Comment: Apologies, I misread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer for $F_X(x)$ is not right. If $x<1$, then $F(x)=0$. Otherwise, for $x>1$:

$$F_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^xf_X(t)dt=\int_1^x \frac{2}{x^3}dx=-\left.\frac{1}{x^2}\right|_1^x.$$

Can you finish it from here?

BTW, as a really simple sanity check, the definition of the CDF, $F(x)$ must satisfy the following: $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} F(x)=1$, $\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}F(x)=0$. You can easily see your answer is immediately wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just apply  the formula on book without paying attention to the scale of $x$. So  $F_X(x)=1-\frac{1}{x^2}$

Comment: @QYang: And be careful, $F_X(x)=0$ for $x<1$.